# tools in masm for files io

Tags: windows, io, standards, masm

How can I operate on files in masm.
I mean using standard libraries included to microsoft (masm).
Or somethning available in windows without linkink libraries.

Comment: More information is needed. Are you writing a program for DOS or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/) site (it will provide you with the basic includes you need).
Use the Win32 API as your RTL (nothing to statically link).
For console IO, see the [GetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683231%28VS.85%29.aspx) call to get you started.
Use INVOKE to handle the Win32 parms call parameters.
Also remember that you can define local variables in a MASM function and MASM will generate all the BP relative addressing for you, as well as the entry and exit sequence. MASM (32-bit) has a number of very handy HLL features (that are broken in 64-bit MASM, btw).

Have fun!